# AllenNLP installation issue - No matching distribution found for torchvision<0.9.0,>=0.8.1

Tags: allennlp

As per demos, we are expected to install AllenNLP using following command:

```
pip install allennlp==2.1.0 allennlp-models==2.1.0
```

But it always throws error:

```
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision<0.9.0,>=0.8.1 (from allennlp==2.1.0) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.3.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision<0.9.0,>=0.8.1 (from allennlp==2.1.0)
```

Have tried installing torchvision separately but the version demanded by AllenNLP is not available at all. As can be seen in error above the torchvision<0.9.0,>=0.8.1 is demanded, but the available versions are ... 0.5.0, 0.9.0 ...
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I can see in the [link](https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/) that there are versions 0.8.1 and 0.8.2 which satisfy your requirement.

[image]

So just try installing with version -

`pip install torchvision==0.8.2`

Better if you do it in a virtual environment.

Comment: It is showing the version.. but same error coming:
Collecting torchvision==0.8.2
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision==0.8.2 (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.3.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision==0.8.2

Comment: finally it worked using command - conda install torchvision==0.8.2 -c pytorch

Answer (score 1):

Finally it worked using this command:

```
conda install torchvision==0.8.2 -c pytorch
```

then:

```
pip install allennlp==2.1.0 allennlp-models==2.1.0
```